# Minimal JSON Parser

Tags: c++, parsing, json

Motivation: Partially for fun / learning, but also so I can roll out a custom JSON-like file format for a fighting game I am writing. There are two caveats: you cannot have repeated keys (requires `std::unordered_multimap`) and the keys are not in order (requires insertion order `std::vector` on the side, or some external boost lib probably). I am mainly looking for critique on my level of comments and ability to read my code, but everything else I am of course welcome to hear.

```
#pragma once

#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace json {
  class Value;

  // six json data types
  using null_t = std::nullptr_t;
  using bool_t = bool;
  using number_t = std::double_t;
  using string_t = std::string;
  using array_t = std::vector<Value>;
  using object_t = std::map<string_t, Value>;

  using aggregate_t = std::variant<
    null_t,   bool_t,  number_t,
    string_t, array_t, object_t>;

  class Value : protected aggregate_t {
  public:
    using aggregate_t::variant;
    // removes spurious E0291
    Value() = default;
    // converts int into double rather than bool
    Value(int integer) : aggregate_t(static_cast<double>(integer)) {}
    // converts c_string (pointer) into string rather than bool
    Value(const char* c_string) : aggregate_t(std::string(c_string)) {}

  public:
    auto operator[](const string_t& key) -> Value& {
      // transform into object if null
      if (std::get_if<null_t>(this))
        *this = object_t();
      return std::get<object_t>(*this)[key];
    }

    auto operator[](std::size_t key) -> Value& {
      // transform into array if null
      if (std::get_if<null_t>(this))
        *this = array_t();
      if (key >= std::get<array_t>(*this).size())
        std::get<array_t>(*this).resize(key + 1);
      return std::get<array_t>(*this)[key];
    }

    auto save(std::ostream& stream, std::string prefix = "") -> std::ostream& {
      static const std::string SPACING = "  "; // "\t"; // "    ";

      // depending on the type, write to correct value with format to stream
      std::visit([&stream, &prefix](auto&& value) {
        using namespace std;
        using T = decay_t<decltype(value)>;

        if constexpr (is_same_v<T, nullptr_t>)
          stream << "null";
        if constexpr (is_same_v<T, bool_t>)
          stream << (value ? "true" : "false");
        else if constexpr (is_same_v<T, double_t>)
          stream << value;
        else if constexpr (is_same_v<T, string>)
          stream << '"' << value << '"';
        else if constexpr (is_same_v<T, array_t>) {
          stream << "[\n";
          auto [indent, remaining] = make_tuple(prefix + SPACING, value.size());
          // for every json value, indent and print to stream
          for (auto& json : value)
            json.save(stream << indent, indent)
              // if jsons remaining (not last), append comma
              << (--remaining ? ",\n" : "\n");
          stream << prefix << "]";
        }
        else if constexpr (is_same_v<T, object_t>) {
          stream << "{\n";
          auto [indent, remaining] = make_tuple(prefix + SPACING, value.size());
          // for every json value, indent with key and print to stream
          for (auto& [key, json] : value)
            json.save(stream << indent << '"' << key << "\" : ", indent)
              // if jsons remaining (not last), append comma
              << (--remaining ? ",\n" : "\n");
          stream << prefix << "}";
        }
        }, *static_cast<aggregate_t*>(this));
      return stream;
    }

    auto load(std::istream& stream) -> std::istream& {
      using namespace std;

      switch ((stream >> ws).peek()) {
      case '"': {
        // get word surrounded by "
        stringbuf buffer;
        stream.ignore(1)
          .get(buffer, '"')
          .ignore(1);
        *this = buffer.str();
      } break;
      case '[': {
        array_t array;
        for (stream.ignore(1); (stream >> ws).peek() != ']';)
          // load child json and consume comma if available
          if ((array.emplace_back().load(stream) >> ws).peek() == ',')
            stream.ignore(1);
        stream.ignore(1);
        *this = move(array);
      } break;
      case '{': {
        object_t object;
        for (stream.ignore(1); (stream >> ws).peek() != '}';) {
          // get word surrounded by "
          stringbuf buffer;
          stream.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '"')
            .get(buffer, '"')
            .ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ':');
          // load child json and consume comma if available
          if ((object[buffer.str()].load(stream) >> ws).peek() == ',')
            stream.ignore(1);
        }
        stream.ignore(1);
        *this = move(object);
      } break;
      default: {
        if (isdigit(stream.peek()) || stream.peek() == '.') {
          double_t number;
          stream >> number;
          *this = number;
        }
        else if (isalpha(stream.peek())) {
          // get alphabetic word
          string word;
          for (; isalpha(stream.peek()); stream.ignore())
            word.push_back(stream.peek());
          // set value to look-up table's value
          static auto keyword_lut = map<string_view, Value>{
            {"true", true}, {"false", false}, {"null", nullptr}};
          *this = keyword_lut[word];
        }
        else
          *this = nullptr;
      } break;
      }

      return stream;
    }

    auto save_to_path(std::string_view file_path) -> void {
      auto file = std::ofstream(std::string(file_path));
      save(file);
    }

    auto load_from_path(std::string_view file_path) -> void {
      auto file = std::ifstream(std::string(file_path));
      load(file);
    }

    static void test() {
      std::stringstream ss;
      {
        json::Value value;

        auto& employee = value["employee"];
        employee["name"] = "bob";
        employee["age"] = 21;
        employee["friends"][0] = "alice";
        employee["friends"][1] = "billy";
        employee["weight"] = 140.0;

        value.save(ss);
      }

      std::cout << ss.str() << "\n\n";

      {
        auto example = std::stringstream(R"(
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "isAlive": true,
      "age": 27,
      "address": {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": "10021-3100"
      },
      "phoneNumbers": [
        {
          "type": "home",
          "number": "212 555-1234"
        },
        {
          "type": "office",
          "number": "646 555-4567"
        },
        {
          "type": "mobile",
          "number": "123 456-7890"
        }
      ],
      "children": [],
      "spouse": null
    })");
        json::Value value;
        value.load(example);

        ss.clear();
        value.save(ss);
      }

      std::cout << ss.str() << "\n\n";
    }
  };
}

int main() {
  json::Value::test();
  return getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through the code and see what can be improved.

---

> ```
> #pragma once
> ```

This shouldn't be in a non-header.

---

> ```
> #include <list>
> #include <map>
> #include <string>
> #include <variant>
> #include <vector>
>
> #include <fstream>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <sstream>
> ```

Sort the include directives in alphabetical order.

---

> ```
> namespace json {
>     class Value;
>
>     // six json data types
>     using null_t = std::nullptr_t;
>     using bool_t = bool;
>     using number_t = std::double_t;
>     using string_t = std::string;
>     using array_t = std::vector<Value>;
>     using object_t = std::map<string_t, Value>;
>
>     using aggregate_t = std::variant<
>         null_t,   bool_t,  number_t,
>         string_t, array_t, object_t>;
> ```

`json` is a very common name used by many people, leading to name clashes.  Think of a more unique name.  Maybe `unicorn5838::json`?

I don't see a reason to use `std::nullptr_t` for `null_t`.  `std::nullptr_t` is a null pointer literal and can implicitly convert to pointers.  Is that plausible?  You can use `std::monostate` instead, or just `struct null_t { };`.

You are mixing `std::double_t` and `double`.  My advice is to just use `double`.  Also, consistently use `number_t` after the alias declaration.

---

> ```
> class Value : protected aggregate_t {
> public:
>     using aggregate_t::variant;
>     // removes spurious E0291
>     Value() = default;
>     // converts int into double rather than bool
>     Value(int integer) : aggregate_t(static_cast<double>(integer)) {}
>     // converts c_string (pointer) into string rather than bool
>     Value(const char* c_string) : aggregate_t(std::string(c_string)) {}
> ```

Hmm ...  Protected inheritance?  Why do you need it in this case?  (You can address this question with a comment if you have a good reason.)

Inheriting the constructors of `std::variant` doesn't seem to be a good choice here.  I see your effort in fixing the problems, but just providing your own constructors seems easier.

---

> ```
> public:
>     auto operator[](const string_t& key) -> Value& {
>         // transform into object if null
>         if (std::get_if<null_t>(this))
>             *this = object_t();
>         return std::get<object_t>(*this)[key];
>     }
>
>     auto operator[](std::size_t key) -> Value& {
>         // transform into array if null
>         if (std::get_if<null_t>(this))
>             *this = array_t();
>         if (key >= std::get<array_t>(*this).size())
>             std::get<array_t>(*this).resize(key + 1);
>         return std::get<array_t>(*this)[key];
>     }
> ```

Don't use multiple `public:` labels.

Do not use the trailing return type syntax unless necessary.  (Yeah, I know some people advocate always using a trailing return type, but it arguably makes the code more verbose.)

Your `operator[]` automatically constructs the element if not existent, much like `map::operator[]` but not `vector::operator[]`.  I'm not sure whether this behavior is intuitive enough to justify itself, but anyway ...

`*this = object_t();` should be `emplace<object_t>();` to prevent an unnecessary move construction.

You do `std::get<array_t>(*this)` three times, and the complex code for getting the value will be run three times.  Instead, use a reference:

```
auto& arr = std::get<array_t>(*this);
if (key >= arr.size())
    arr.resize(key + 1);
return arr[key];
```

Also note that `key + 1` may overflow (well, probably not a real problem).

> ```
> auto save(std::ostream& stream, std::string prefix = "") -> std::ostream& {
>     static const std::string SPACING = "  "; // "\t"; // "    ";
>
>     // depending on the type, write to correct value with format to stream
>     std::visit([&stream, &prefix](auto&& value) {
>             using namespace std;
>             using T = decay_t<decltype(value)>;
>
>             if constexpr (is_same_v<T, nullptr_t>)
>                              stream << "null";
>             if constexpr (is_same_v<T, bool_t>)
>                              stream << (value ? "true" : "false");
>             else if constexpr (is_same_v<T, double_t>)
>                                   stream << value;
>             else if constexpr (is_same_v<T, string>)
>                                   stream << '"' << value << '"';
>             else if constexpr (is_same_v<T, array_t>) {
>                     stream << "[\n";
>                     auto [indent, remaining] = make_tuple(prefix + SPACING, value.size());
>                     // for every json value, indent and print to stream
>                     for (auto& json : value)
>                         json.save(stream << indent, indent)
>                             // if jsons remaining (not last), append comma
>                             << (--remaining ? ",\n" : "\n");
>                     stream << prefix << "]";
>                 }
>             else if constexpr (is_same_v<T, object_t>) {
>                     stream << "{\n";
>                     auto [indent, remaining] = make_tuple(prefix + SPACING, value.size());
>                     // for every json value, indent with key and print to stream
>                     for (auto& [key, json] : value)
>                         json.save(stream << indent << '"' << key << "\" : ", indent)
>                             // if jsons remaining (not last), append comma
>                             << (--remaining ? ",\n" : "\n");
>                     stream << prefix << "}";
>                 }
>         }, *static_cast<aggregate_t*>(this));
>     return stream;
> }
> ```

Use `null_t` and `string_t`, not `nullptr_t` and `string`.  Use `const auto&` instead of `auto&&` if you don't need the universal reference semantics.  `prefix` should be `std::string_view` instead of by-value `std::string`.  The spacing should also be an argument instead of hard coded.

This is a very long function.  The long if constexpr chain makes the code much less readable.  Use overload resolution to break it down:

```
// somewhere
struct formatter {
    std::ostream& os;
    std::string_view prefix;
    std::string_view indent;

    void operator()(null_t) const;
    void operator()(bool_t) const;
    // etc.
};
```

then you can just do

```
std::visit(formatter{os, prefix, indent}, static_cast<aggregate_t&>(*this));
```

The string streaming should use `std::quoted` to properly handle escaping.

Don't do this:

```
auto [indent, remaining] = make_tuple(prefix + SPACING, value.size());
```

It incurs a lot of overhead, both on performance and readability.

---

> ```
> auto load(std::istream& stream) -> std::istream& {
>     using namespace std;
>
>     switch ((stream >> ws).peek()) {
>     case '"': {
>         // get word surrounded by "
>         stringbuf buffer;
>         stream.ignore(1)
>             .get(buffer, '"')
>             .ignore(1);
>         *this = buffer.str();
>     } break;
>     case '[': {
>         array_t array;
>         for (stream.ignore(1); (stream >> ws).peek() != ']';)
>             // load child json and consume comma if available
>             if ((array.emplace_back().load(stream) >> ws).peek() == ',')
>                 stream.ignore(1);
>         stream.ignore(1);
>         *this = move(array);
>     } break;
>     case '{': {
>         object_t object;
>         for (stream.ignore(1); (stream >> ws).peek() != '}';) {
>             // get word surrounded by "
>             stringbuf buffer;
>             stream.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '"')
>                 .get(buffer, '"')
>                 .ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ':');
>             // load child json and consume comma if available
>             if ((object[buffer.str()].load(stream) >> ws).peek() == ',')
>                 stream.ignore(1);
>         }
>         stream.ignore(1);
>         *this = move(object);
>     } break;
>     default: {
>         if (isdigit(stream.peek()) || stream.peek() == '.') {
>             double_t number;
>             stream >> number;
>             *this = number;
>         }
>         else if (isalpha(stream.peek())) {
>             // get alphabetic word
>             string word;
>             for (; isalpha(stream.peek()); stream.ignore())
>                 word.push_back(stream.peek());
>             // set value to look-up table's value
>             static auto keyword_lut = map<string_view, Value>{
>                 {"true", true}, {"false", false}, {"null", nullptr}};
>             *this = keyword_lut[word];
>         }
>         else
>             *this = nullptr;
>     } break;
>     }
>
>     return stream;
> }
> ```

Don't use `stringbuf`.  It's a low level functionality.  Use `std::quoted` instead:

```
case '"': {
    std::string str;
    stream >> std::quoted(str);
    emplace<string_t>(str);
    break;
}
```

`.ignore(1)` is slower than `.get()` without aggressive optimization.

The table should be `const`, and `.at` (which looks up existing elements) should be used instead of `[]` (which creates new elements and cannot be used on `const` maps).  Using a `map` for three strings is also an overkill and will introduce overhead.

---

> ```
> auto save_to_path(std::string_view file_path) -> void {
>     auto file = std::ofstream(std::string(file_path));
>     save(file);
> }
>
> auto load_from_path(std::string_view file_path) -> void {
>     auto file = std::ifstream(std::string(file_path));
>     load(file);
> }
> ```

Please don't "always use `auto`".  I know it is suggested by Herb Sutter (right?), but it is really unidiomatic and distracting.

Comment: I've gone ahead and made all the corrections except the follow (please refute me if I am wrong): `#pragma once` it is a header file, `protected aggregate_t` because a json IS-A variant, not HAS-A variant, multiple `public:` labels separates my ctors / API and trailing returns is my coding style (I would change depending on my org).

Comment: ah two more notes: I can't use `std::string_view` for `prefix` because I require append operations to tabify my json -> file operation, second I use a `std::map` lookup table even if it is overkill because its easy to read and I will be adding my own custom keywords for my fighting game.

Comment: @Saxpy "Is-a" should be indicated by private inheritance, not protected inheritance.  Don't abuse multiple `public:` labels, which alter semantics, for separating declaration blocks; using a comment like `// constructors` instead is much clearer.  Always trailing return is a, well, unpopular, and illogical style (coding styles exist to improve readability).  `string_view` provides the operations you want.  Keeping the map is understandable though, but at least make it `const`.

Comment: I see, I'll go ahead and change it to private inheritance. Also I'll take note on the `public:` blocks into `// constructors`. I'd still like to keep trailing returns at this is my personal project and that's the style I've committed too and prefer on my own. `string_view` does not offer append operations though, how could I refactor this? The `std::map` will be const.

Comment: @Saxpy Can you elaborate on “string view does not offer append operations”?  You can concatenate them just like ordinary strings.

Comment: IIRC `string_view` is supposed to be a read-only view of a c-string. [string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) contains no APIs for mutations, only reducing the view.

Comment: @Saxpy You can still do `sv + sv` or `sv + s` because `is_constructible<string, string_view>`.

Comment: `sv + sv` and `sv + s` fails on both Clang 8 and MSVC2019. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636549/why-is-there-no-support-for-concatenating-stdstring-and-stdstring-view) from 2 years ago, but in any case I'd still prefer using a plain `string` as it is meant to be appended anyways.

Comment: @Saxpy Oops, I didn’t realize that the string view ctor is explicit.  Sorry, I’ll reconsider the recommendation